# Which mail log analyzer can I use for sendmail?

Tags: sendmail, email, logging

I need to analyse my mail log to find out who consumes the most bandwidth (or find out if there is any spam mail send through my server) Which mail log analyser serves the best purpose? FYI, I have copy the logs to my local computer already and the analysing process will have to be done locally. My machine is running on Fedora, but if there is any free and good mail log analyser that runs on Windows, I don't mind to give it a try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good sendmail log analyzer?](http://serverfault.com/questions/1808/what-is-a-good-sendmail-log-analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [SendmailAnalyzer](http://sareport.darold.net/index.html).

**Here is how you can install it on Fedora**

First install tool for building RPM packages

```
yum install rpm-build
```

Next, download sorces from sourceforge.net

```
wget "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sa-report/sa-report/8.7/sendmailanalyzer-8.7.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fsa-report%2F&ts=1363055890&use_mirror=iweb"
```

Create work directories

```
mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{SOURCES,SPECS}
```

Extract spec file from the tarball

```
tar xf sendmailanalyzer-8.7.tar.gz -C ~/rpmbuild/SPECS --strip-components=3 sendmailanalyzer-8.7/packaging/RPM/sendmailanalyzer.spec
```

Dive into SPECS folder

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
```

And build the package

```
rpmbuild -bb sendmailanalyzer.spec
```

Finally you can install it with yum

```
yum localinstall ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/sendmailanalyzer-8.7-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

**Some post installation work to do:**

Uncomment the following line in /etc/cron.d/sendmailanalyzer

```
0 1 * * * root /usr/bin/sa_cache > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Uncomment the content of /etc/httpd/conf.d/sendmailanalyzer.conf and add place from where you wish to acces the reports (your IP or "all")

```
Allow from 192.168.1.2
```

Reload configuration

```
systemctl reload httpd.service
```

Start sendmailanalyzer

```
systemctl start sendmailanalyzer.service
```

Enable autostart

```
systemctl enable sendmailanalyzer.service
```

If you would like to examine the graphs right away you don't need to wait for cron job. Just update the cache manually with

```
/usr/bin/sa_cache
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The asker wanted just a TIP on what could he possibly use. The guide to implement suggested option is just a bonus.

Comment: Please read [this QA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/136475). Answers here are not only for the OP, but for anyone that happens to come across this page in the future. What happens when those links go dead? Then your answer is **worthless**. Which is why we don't appreciate link-only answers.

Comment: Sorry I'm new around here. Thank you for educating me. Answer fixed.

Comment: No problem. Looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Installing that MIMEDefang and doing what you want via [filter_recipient](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) will give you more measurement flexibility.